# intent called with startActivity not changing my activity

Tags: java, android, android-room

I've looked at related posts but the solutions on those don't seem to be working for me.

I'm trying to use an intent to start my second activity, however it doesn't seem to be firing it.

My manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SetupActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

My Intent in SetupActivity

```
if(user != null) {
        System.out.println("User exists!");
        Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        System.out.println("Starting new activity");
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("User does not exist!");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
    }
```

My HomeActivity class (print and setContentView not happening)

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    System.out.println("Redirected to Home Activity!");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use Log.d("tag","message") to print out message on the console.

Change this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    System.out.println("Redirected to Home Activity!");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
```

to

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Redirected to Home Activity!");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
```

PersistableBundle is not going to be called during normal Activity startup